# Local Service account canot write to filesystem

Tags: c#, service

I have created a simple Windows service, following these youtube videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2aFNtcZfk.

This works, so long as I don't try to do any logging. If I call my logging function:

```
    public static void LogMsg(LogMsgTypes msgType, string msg)
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        string logFileName = string.Format("{0}Recalculator{1:yyyyMMdd}.log",path, DateTime.Now);
        var file = System.IO.File.AppendText(logFileName);

        file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1,-9} : {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), msgType, msg));

        file.Close();
    }
```

then the service crashes and I get an Unauthorized Access Exception error in the Windows Event Log. I know I should be logging to the Event Log anyway, but I gather I will have to create the source manually first and I would really like to be able to write to a file if possible. On the youtube tutorial I am following, the guy gets no errors at all.

Comment: As you already stated, you need to create the event log source first.  So what's the issue?

Comment: Probably just that I am being lazy and need to learn how to set up Visual Studio Installer projects to do things like creating Event Log Sources. For now, the service is running under Local System, which gives it the credentials to write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is probably that I should do it 'right' by creating a source in the Windows Event Log and then writing to there instead of to a custom log file.

For now, I have just installed the service to run under Local System.